# CMD: Sort files in folder structure

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a BAT that automatically sorts the ZIPs in the input folder into the corresponding target folder.

All ZIPs begin with a serial number 001 File.zip, 002 File.zip, 003 File.zip, etc.

The target folders are named according to the same scheme: 001, 002, 003, ..., 999.

So if a ZIP comes into the input folder, it should automatically be assigned to the corresponding target folder with the same number.

But since the target folder is up to 999 I don't want to write all paths beforehand ...

So far my code looks like this:

```
SET input=C:\Daten\Input
SET target=C:\Daten\Target

for /r %input% %%a in (*.zip) do (
Set FILE=%%~nxa
Set FILEWITHOUTEXT=%%~na

Set SPLITABLE_NAME=!FILEWITHOUTEXT:_= !
for %%t in (!SPLITABLE_NAME!) do set FIRSTTOKEN=%%t
)
copy /Y %%a %target%\!FIRSTTOKEN!\!FILE!
```

Unfortunately, the whole thing just doesn't work at all.

Comment: `for %%t in (!SPLITABLE_NAME!) do set FIRSTTOKEN=%%t` puts *each* token into the (same) variable, leaving you with the *last*  token. Use `for /f "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%t in ("%~na") do  set "FIRSTTOKEN=%%t"` instead.

Comment: I tried that but it wont sort the ZIPs in the respective files. Do u have another idea?

Comment: @Proki, the code is missing a % symbol. `("%%~na")`

Comment: Regardless of that your input file name example never showed underscores in the file name. Going forward make sure you always provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are also doing the copy outside of the `FOR` command which means it will only copy the last file that is iterated.  You also don't need to assign any FOR variables to environmental variables. Which means you wouldn't need to use delayed expansion at all. Just use the FOR variables. Actually it won't copy any file because you are using %%a for the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Stephan's comment and some additional code cleanup and best practice usage your code should look like this.

```
:sort
SET "input=C:\Daten\Input"
SET "target=C:\Daten\Target"

for /r "%input%" %%a in (*.zip) do (
    For /f "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%t in ("%%~na") do (
        copy /Y "%%~a" "%target%\%%t\"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
May I ask another question? 
If the input isnt a ZIP but a folder with the same naming scheme (001-999), how would I change the code so the data within the folder is copied to the target folder (but not the folder itself)?

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have already selected and answer. If you wanted to push ahead into a modern day scripting language, you could consider using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows platform, PowerShell will be available.

Once you are confident that the files will be correctly copied, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Daten\Input' -Filter '???_*.zip' |" ^
        'ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_.Name -match '^(\d{3})_.*') {" ^
                "Copy-Item $_.FullName "C:\Daten\Target\$($Matches[1])" -Whatif" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```